# Couldn't send email in Redmine

Tags: redmine

I try to send email in Redmine with sendmail method, but I don't receive any email. 
Therefore, I tried configuring smtp email setup in Redmine using the following parameters, but I get the error "An error occurred while sending mail (execution expired)".

```
production:
  email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:
      address: "box784.bluehost.com"
      port: 465
      authentication: :plain
      user_name: "username+domain.com"
      password: password
      enable_starttls_auto: true
```

my Information:

```
Environment:
  Redmine version                          2.1.4.stable
  Ruby version                             1.8.7 (x86_64-linux)
  Rails version                            3.2.8
  Environment                              production
  Database adapter                         MySQL
Redmine plugins:
  no plugin installed
```

Answer (score 4):

After a couple of very late nights playing with all the settings in the configuration.yml file, I have finally been able to get email notifications to work with Redmine on Bluehost. Getting it to work with SMTP was a futile exercise, and Bluehost wasn't very helpful with getting it resolved, however I got it working using sendmail. The trick is to add a couple extra parameters, which really should be documented in the Redmine Wiki help. Here is a copy of my configuration.yml file, which works. It's the enable_starttls_auto and authentication settings that make it work (go figure). Make sure you get the spacing right (each indent has 2 spaces):

```
production:  
    email_delivery:
        delivery_method: :sendmail
        sendmail_settings:
            arguments: -i
            enable_starttls_auto: false
            authentication: :none
```

Finally! Working Sendmail with Redmine on Bluehost!

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent quite a few hours trying all combos of settings myself. I'm on Bluehost also. At first your settings didn't work either. But that was because I had them under "default:" with nothing under "production:" I thought that meant to use the default setting unless something is overridden. But it only worked when I put all the settings also under "production:" I would modify the Redmine Wiki if I understood why those arguments are needed for Bluehost. Just saying "Use this for Bluehost" doesn't seem the way to go.

Comment: One other point: These setting turn off authentication between the server that our apps are running on and the server hosting the Bluehost SMTP service. Therefore the passwords will be sent in plain text. Is this of any concern?

Answer (score 0):

[image: production: email_delivery: delivery_method: :smtp smtp_settings: enable_starttls_auto: true address: "smtp.office365.com" port: 587 domain: "poopcode.com" authentication: :login user_name: "heyhey@poopcode.com" password: "PoopCoDe123!"]

This configuration works. You can use the test email feature in Redmine to test this.

Source: https://poopcode.com/configure-outlook-email-in-redmine/